# selecting nodes vs. dragging the graph in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have a small cytoscape.js example here:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/cyprob/standalone.html

Note that if I click a node, and then click outside the node (but still in the graph div), I go into this strange mode where when I move the mouse, the whole graph moves. I can't get out of this mode except by reloading the page.

I have another version of this same page:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/cyprob/standalone-noevents.html

In this version, I can click nodes or anywhere in the graph, and I don't enter that strange graph-dragging mode.

The only difference between these two versions is that the first one has an event listener in the ready method:

```
cy.on('click', function(evt){
    console.log("the cytoscape graph was clicked");
    window.evt = evt;
    console.log( 'clicked ' + evt.cyTarget.id() );
});
```

So my question is...how do I get out of that graph-dragging mode? And can I have an event listener that won't cause me to go into that mode?

Comment: This has already been fixed, see:
https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/commit/c03ec996a258963dae7da83a246ae3de3c36e1f9
Thanks to Joe Cheng for tracking this down.